# example of a infinityloop by optimization(done by the compiler) in C++ in Visual Studio2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-optimization

I have to do a demonstration of how the compiler produces a infinity-loop while optimizing a program.

I have to show it in C++ in Visual Studio 2010 and I think he best way to show it is with and without volatile.

I used the code from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
and tried it with and without volatile(and compile with: /EHsc /O2) 
But there is no infinity-loop. 
I also change it like that :

```
// compile with: /EHsc /O2

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

//volatile bool Sentinel = true;
bool Sentinel = true;
int CriticalData = 0;
int round=0;

unsigned ThreadFunc1() {
   while (Sentinel){
        Sleep(10);   // volatile spin lock   
        cout << "Critical Data = " << CriticalData << endl; 
   }
   return 0;
} 
unsigned  ThreadFunc2() {
   Sleep(2000);
   CriticalData++; 
   Sentinel = false; 
   return 0;
}

int main() {
   HANDLE hThread1, hThread2; 

   hThread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&ThreadFunc1, NULL, 0, NULL);
   hThread2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&ThreadFunc2, NULL, 0, NULL);

   CloseHandle(hThread1);
   CloseHandle(hThread2);

   system("pause");
}
```

But no infinity-loop. Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not know *for sure* what `Sleep(int)` and `iostream.operator <<()` can do with your global variables. It's possible (from its point of view), that they can change `Sentinel` variable, so compiler can't remove reading of `Sentinel` from the loop.

Comment: if someone else wants to know: i deleted the sleep and put the cout out of the loop. now it does what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem here? The compiler *may* produce an infinite loop without volatile, but it doesn't have to. It's more likely to see an infinite loop when compiling with highest optimization level and turning debug info off.

Comment: i tried it with o2 and with ox (available in vs2010) and in release mode... but ther is no loop(and i tried it a lot of times).. i have to show a loop where the condition is optimizes and an infinity-loop has to be the result...

Comment: Yes, but the compiler _may_ optimize the read access to `Sentinel` away. It doesn't have to. Try placing both methods in different compilation units - in such a simple example, it is possible that the compiler is clever enough to "see" that the variable might change. However, there is no guarantee this will go wrong, as there is none that it will work. It's like driving without your seatbelt on - you might get into trouble while most of the time it works.

Comment: the problem is it has to be simple... I have seen an example in c# a year ago or something and it was as simple as this and it did the optimization every time, so i thought it has something to do with vs2010(and its compiler). I will try it with different files, maybe you are right and the compiler notices it if it is in the same file..

Answer (score 0):

```
int gIMightBeUseful = 1;

void foo()
{
  int bar;
  while(!bar){gIMightBeUseful++;}
}
```

Has a chance of infinite looping depending on optimization level.  Or does it have to be thread interlock specific?

Comment: Uhm... The code uses an uninitialized variable, which means that it might be an infinite loop regardless of optimization. I believe that the question is about a piece of code that is *correct* when read by a human but that the compiler can break due to optimizations (not performing reads for all accesses, caching writes...)

Comment: there is no change to bar... i need a code where the compiler makes an infinity-loop out of a loop that can be changed from outside. i think that is only possible with threading or hardware elements(with i will not have when i have to perform it)...

Comment: Is that homework? Who would need such a code? I mean, you want an infinite loop, you just write `for(;;);` or `while (true)`...

Comment: The idea here being that debug code quite often will clear stack vars for you on assignment while optimized builds will not.  It's a solution that's as silly as the question.

Comment: it has to show what can go wrong(with optimization). I do not need a infinityloop that i wriht, i need a infinityloop the compiler produces(as you can see in my example). And I need it for a presentation about the problems and how they can be prevented...